# Controlling a stepper motor with javascript

Tags: gpio, python, networking, hardware

I'm trying to control atleast 2 stepper motors with the raspberry, which works fine with the following setup:

- Raspberrypi Model 2
- MotorHAT from Adafruit https://www.adafruit.com/products/2348
- Python scripts

So at this moment I am forced to use the Python scripts, because the MotorHAT has only a Python library. Now I've found a Javascript library for stepper motors, which is actually for arduino boards, but still has raspberry support.
The library is called Johnny-Five http://johnny-five.io/examples/stepper-driver/ I tried to set the library up and got now the following javascript:

```
var raspi = require('raspi-io');
var five = require('johnny-five');
var board = new five.Board({
   io: new raspi()
});

board.on("ready", function() {

  var stepper = new five.Stepper({
    type: five.Stepper.TYPE.DRIVER,
    stepsPerRev: 200,
     pins: {
     step: 11,
     dir: 13
    }
 });


stepper.rpm(180).ccw().accel(1600).decel(1600).step(2000, function() {

console.log("Done moving CCW");

// once first movement is done, make 10 revolutions clockwise at previously
//      defined speed, accel, and decel by passing an object into stepper.step
stepper.step({
  steps: 2000,
  direction: five.Stepper.DIRECTION.CW
}, function() {
  console.log("Done moving CW");
});
});
});
```

This script prints the following error:

```
  Error: Stepper is not supported
    at new Stepper ...
    at Board ...
    at Board.emit (events.js:92.17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
```

If anyone could figure out my fault or knows a better solution to control the stepper motors from a website, that would be great!

Comment: 1) Is the JavaScript library said to be compatible with the Pi. 2) Do not make us guess errors, it is very annoying.  If you have error messages put the exact text in your question.

Comment: I updated the question for the Error message and I already wrote : ..."which is actually for arduino boards, but still has raspberry support."

Comment: I can see no suggestion that the JavaScript you link will work on the Pi.  A script comment explicity calls up Arduino code.

Comment: This is arduino code right, but if you look at my link and at this code you can see some differences, the header is changed for raspberry pi, like the johnny-five library suggests, I can't explain everything here, if u don't look at the material i tried to provide in my question :/

Comment: Hopefully someone else will trawl through the web-site to find the information to which you refer.

Comment: Yeah im hoping for someone who maybe already knows this library

Comment: Did you flash the stepper board as per this comment: 
`/**
   * In order to use the Stepper class, your board must be flashed with
   * either of the following:
   *
   * - AdvancedFirmata https://github.com/soundanalogous/AdvancedFirmata
   * - ConfigurableFirmata https://github.com/firmata/arduino/releases/tag/v2.6.2
   *
   */` (unless of course they mean flashing the Arduino). The site itself has very little info about using this Stepper-Driver with the Raspberry Pi (I could find NONE).

Comment: If the "flashing your board" comment refers to the Arduino, you are out of luck, and the Stepper class is not supported on the RPi (unless you hack deep into the Firmata code and port it to the RPi).

Comment: Mhm I think you are right, there are just some parts of the library working with the pi like led blink and so on

Comment: It uses Node.JS, and the error is related to that. It seems like the the stepper class, is reporting that whatever it is trying to do (at events.js:92.17) , is not supported on the Pi, as per the error message. It could be a call to Node.JS and this error is originating from the C class.. not JS script. MotorHAT uses I2C, are you sure everything relating to I2C is configured OK on the Pi? Possibly whatever Node.JS is trying to do on the I2C channel is not supported by MotorHAT

Comment: A new NPM module for Node.js has been published for driving steppers on the Pi ... it can be found here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stepper-wiringpi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This library, which didn't exist in the past as I asked this question solves this problem. https://www.npmjs.com/package/stepper-wiringpi

Answer (score 0):

Johnny-five does not support stepper for Raspberry pie model boards.
You can see it [here](http://johnny-five.io/platform-support/#raspberry-pi-3-model-b).

If you want to control steppers, I suggest you use Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

to escape python i use the following javascript library

https://www.npmjs.com/package/motor-hat
full supports for MotorHAT from Adafruit https://www.adafruit.com/products/2348

Answer (score -2):

I think you forgot to upload the [Advanced Firmata](https://github.com/soundanalogous/AdvancedFirmata), which have the codes for Steppers, to your Arduino.

How to upload the Advanced Firmata to your Arduino:

Clone or download and copy AdvancedFirmata into your Arduino projects/sketch directory (or anywhere on your hard drive). Open in the Arduino IDE, verify and upload to your board.

If you download rather than clone this repository, rename the folder to "AdvancedFirmata" after unzipping and before copying into your Arduino projects directory.

Remember to choose correct Board, Processor and Port.

Comment: How would the OP determine if that is the problem? How would he upload this firmata?